# Use AWS S3 vs Cloudfront

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Since heroku file system is ephemeral , I am planning on using AWS for static assets for my django project on heroku

I am seeing two conflicting articles one which advises on using AWS S3. This one says to use S3

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

While another one below says, S3 has disadvantages and to use Cloudfront CDN instead

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

> Many developers make use of Amazon’s S3 service for serving static
>   assets that have been uploaded previously, either manually or by some
>   form of build process. Whilst this works, this is not recommended as
>   S3 was designed as a file storage service and not for optimal delivery
>   of files under load. Therefore, serving static assets from S3 is not
>   recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon CloudFront is a Content Delivery Network (CDN) that integrates with other Amazon Web Services like S3 that give us an easy way to distribute content to end users with low latency, high data transfer speeds.

CloudFront makes your static files available from data centers around the world (called edge locations). When a visitor requests a file from your website, he or she is invisibly redirected to a copy of the file at the nearest edge location (Now AWS has around 35 edge locations spread across the world), which results in faster download times than if the visitor had accessed the content from S3 bucket located in a particular region.

So if your user base is spread across the world its a better option to use CloudFront else if your users are localized you would not find much difference using CloudFront than S3 (but in this case you need to choose right location for your your S3 bucket: US East, US West, Asia Pacific, EU, South America etc)

[Comparative features of Amazon S3 and CloudFront](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/cloudfront--amazon-s3-vs-amazon-cloudfront.html)

Comment: Another bonus point in CloudFront is that CloudFront allows you to set different domain aliases for your CloudFront distribution.i.e:You can have domain1.example.com, domain2.example.com and domain3.example.com pointing to the same CloudFront distribution, allowing parallel downloads

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use CloudFront on top of [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/). You will be serving the static assets directly from your Heroku app, but CloudFront as the CDN will take over once you reach scale.

Whitenoise radically simplifies build processes and the need to use convoluted caching headers.

Read http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/ for the full manifesto.

(Note that Whitenoise is relevant only for static assets bundled with your app, not for user-uploaded files, which still require S3 for proper storage. You'd still want to use CF though.)

Comment: I know the Heroku docs recommend Whitenoise, but they also recommend that Repo sizes should be <600MB (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#repository-size), does that change your recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should use both.

CloudFront only acts as a CDN, which basically means it caches resources in edge locations all over the world. In order for this to work, it has to initially download those resources from an origin location, whenever they expire or don't yet exist.

CloudFront distributions can have one of two possible origin types. S3 or EC2. In your case, you should store your assets in S3 and connect the bucket to a CloudFront distribution. Use the CloudFront links for actually serving the assets, and S3 for storage.

This will ensure the best possible performance, as well as correct and scalable load handling.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need additional info in the comments section.